# How to install KDE on Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, kde

I want to install KDE on my Ubuntu but I want to use only KDE and remove GNOME. I want to keep my data on the computer. What should I do?

When i run :
    sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
the terminal shows me this error :
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kubuntu-desktop : Depends: dolphin but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: kinfocenter but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: kwin
               Depends: okular but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: powerdevil but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: sddm-theme-breeze but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: amarok but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: apturl-kde but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: baloo-utils but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: cryptsetup but it is not installable
               Recommends: k3b but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kate but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kde-telepathy but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kdeconnect-plasma but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: krdc but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: ktorrent but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: kwin-addons but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-base but it is not installable
               Recommends: libreoffice-kde but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-style-oxygen but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-discover but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-discover-updater but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-nm but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: plasma-widgets-addons but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: skanlite but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Take a look at this - https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=111845

Comment: An answer was added. Please check if that works

Answer (score 1):

As I see you want to completely remove Gnome and use KDE instead, you can use [purebuntu script](https://github.com/aysiu/purebuntu)

1. Download the `purebuntu.py` file from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/aysiu/purebuntu).

   ```
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aysiu/purebuntu/master/purebuntu.py
   ```
2. Install the `apt-rdepends` package using the terminal command

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends
   ```
3. Run the `purebuntu.py` script telling it, you want to remove `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and keep install `kubuntu-desktop`

   ```
   python purebuntu.py --remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop --keep kubuntu-desktop > apt-command
   ```

   This will generate and output a long `apt-get` command in a file named `apt-command`.
4. Open the `apt-command` file and copy the command generated. Then paste the command in terminal and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

That will remove packages of `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and install `kubuntu-desktop`. **Be warned** that, the system may go into pristine Kubuntu state. You might need to install the extra packages you installed again.

Comment: Are you sure that the link is correct ? I can't connect .

Comment: yes. i can connect. i tested it myself

Comment: @Vilfe or you can download and save it from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aysiu/purebuntu/master/purebuntu.py

Comment: whats happend ?

Comment: @Vilfe it worked obviously. Please edit your question and post the output of `apt-cache policy` in it.